# JavaScript: Use Join to Make Array a String Using Input Argument as Separator Btw Words --> Replace Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join, replace

I have the following code:

```js
function myJoin(array, separator) {

  let newStr = array.join(separator).replace("\", "")

    return newStr

  }

  myJoin(['let\'s', 'make', 'a', 'list'], ' ');
```

I expect the output to be: "let's make  a list" but instead it gives me an error.

```
evalmachine.<anonymous>:21
  let newStr = array.join(separator).replace("\", "")
                                                   ^^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

What's wrong with my replace method?

Comment: `array.join(separator).replace("\\", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `"\"`. The backslash escapes the end quote, meaning the string is unclosed. It should be `"\\"` instead.

Here's a code example:

```js
function myJoin(array, separator) {
  const newStr = array.join(separator).replace('\\', '')
  return newStr
}

const result = myJoin(['let\'s', 'make', 'a', 'list'], ' ')
console.log(result)
```

If you're interested, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)'s an article on escape characters.

Comment: @PineNuts0 No, it doesn't. I just added a console.log, you can run it to check.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need `replace()`**

The `\` in your string isn't really a character — it's part of an escape sequence. As a result, you don't need to replace it unless you are trying to replace actual, literal backslashes in the string. This does what you would expect:

```js
function myJoin(array, separator) {
    return array.join(separator) // you don't need replace here
}
  
console.log(myJoin(['let\'s', 'make', 'a', 'list'], ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping the `"` inside of your replace, you have to use 2 backslashes, ie: `\\`. Also, `replace()` is not a function for arrays, this must be done on a `string`, so you must also swap put `join()` before `replace()`.

This will do the trick:

```js
console.log(['let\'s', 'make', 'a', 'list'].join(" ").replace("\\", ""));
```

It looks like you would like this to be applied to `array`'s  specifically, how about prototypes?

```js
Array.prototype.replace = function(separator = " ") {
  return this.join(separator).replace("\\", "");
};

// Can be called like so 
console.log(['let\'s', 'make', 'a', 'list'].replace(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `"\"`. Backslash is a quoting character in JavaScript which causes the next character to be treated literally.  You need to write `"\\"` to create a string of one backslash character.